# MSBuildWorkspace.Create seems to be not working properly in VB

Tags: vb.net, msbuild, roslyn

In VS 2017, .Net Framework 4.7.1, I use the code below to get a list of C# source files in a project and currentProject.HasDocuments always returns False. There are no errors returned.

```
Using Workspace As MSBuildWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create()
    Dim currentProject As Project = Workspace.OpenProjectAsync(ProjectPath).Result
    Workspace.LoadMetadataForReferencedProjects = True
    If currentProject.HasDocuments Then
        For Each document As Document In currentProject.Documents
            Dim DocumentName As String = document.Name
            ProcessFile(document.FilePath, currentProject.MetadataReferences.ToArray)
        Next document
    End If
End Using
```